# Best way to convert a unix timestamp to javascript date-time

Tags: javascript, unix

I have been following [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript/31918739#31918739) thread for answer but looks like single digit time (0-9) is parsed as it is. The accepted answer

```
// Create a new JavaScript Date object based on the timestamp
// multiplied by 1000 so that the argument is in milliseconds, not seconds.
var date = new Date(unix_timestamp*1000);
// Hours part from the timestamp
var hours = date.getHours();
// Minutes part from the timestamp
var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
// Seconds part from the timestamp
var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();

// Will display time in 10:30:23 format
var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(-2);
```

We get like 2:3:9 instead of 02:03:09. How to get rid of this behaviour? Also can anyone please elaborate on how to get am/pm along with time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var formattedTime = ('0' + hours).substr(-2) + ':'
                + ('0' + minutes).substr(-2) + ':' 
                + ('0' + seconds).substr(-2);
```

I think I will leave the am:pm bit to you. Press ctrl-shift j and play with your code in the console right here

```
//                                 /*Year m-1 d h m s ms*/
unix_timestamp = Math.floor(new Date(2016,0,  1,5,5,0,0)/1000)
```

This might be easier to understand. I have kept it closer

```
// Create a new JavaScript Date object based on the timestamp
// multiplied by 1000 so that the argument is in milliseconds, not seconds.
var date = new Date(unix_timestamp*1000);
// Hours part from the timestamp
var amPm = date.getHours() >= 12?'AM':'PM'
// % is modulo which is the remainder after division || will change 0 to 12
// because 0 is falsey everything else will be left as it is
var hours = ("0" + ((date.getHours() % 12)||12)).substr(-2)
// Minutes part from the timestamp
var minutes = ("0" + date.getMinutes()).substr(-2)
// Seconds part from the timestamp
var seconds = ("0" + date.getSeconds()).substr(-2)

// Will display time in 10:30:23 format
var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes+ ':' + seconds + ' '+ amPm
```

Comment: This works like charm but I have a small query. How does it understand if it has to append a `0` or no. For values less than 9 it should append and for more than 10 it should not.

Comment: the `.substr` takes the last 2 chars in the string so 10 am becomes the string '010' which becomes '10'. I will post a better answer for you because I should make it match the way your example was posted, as the only problem with the original is that no 0 was pre-pended for the hours.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to get rid of the `substr`-part, since the value should already be correct.

Note: you need to check if the values are already above 9, because you don't need to append anything when it is above 9.

**Example**

```
var d = new Date() //Is in milliseconds

var hours = d.getHours();
var minutes = d.getMinutes();
var seconds = d.getSeconds();

console.log(hours + ":" + ((minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + ((seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds))
```

I want to add that these kinds of problems can be easily resolved with using a good library like moment.js