# Convert UTC to browser local time and vice versa dynamically using angularjs(new to angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just wanted a code how a UTC time converted to browser local time and vice versa dynamically without using moment.js needed only pure angular

Tried with  Using AngularJS date filter with UTC date but i want dynamic conversion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert UTC date time to local date time using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time-using-javascript)

Comment: @sachilaranawaka—maybe, but the accepted answer is awful.

Comment: What is your "UTC time"? Is it a string? Number? Date?

Comment: @RobG its a Number

Comment: @HK123—in that case, this is likely a duplicate of [*Best way to convert a unix timestamp to javascript date-time*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40083122/best-way-to-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-javascript-date-time). There are also many answers for formatting Dates, see [*Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript?s=1|20.2780)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can change the date to local and UTC.

```js
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = d;
document.getElementById("local").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
document.getElementById("utc").innerHTML = d.toUTCString();
document.getElementById("fromutc").innerHTML = Date(d.toUTCString());
```

```html
Date => <span id="date"></span><br>
Local => <span id="local"></span><br> 
UTC => <span id="utc"></span><br> 
FromUTC => <span id="fromutc"></span><br>
```

Also find here the reference of all the dateTime functions available in javascript

[JavaScript Date Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

[ECMA Date Reference](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-objects)

[MDN Date Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Please do not reference w3schools. Use [*ECMA-262*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-objects) as a normative reference and [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) where further explanation and examples will help.

Comment: @Manish Thank you....it works.......it seems to be of javascript......is there a method we can do this stuff using angular(any angular related functinalities)?....

Comment: @HK123 no nothing similar to this is there is angular. Angular implements dates just as a filter[Date reference Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) You have to do it using javascript and also angular is itself built on javascript so this should be fine. Apart from this i'm not aware of any angular module that handles dates (if exists) you might have to google may find one..

Comment: @Manish—it would be better if you removed the w3schools link completely. The information presented has errors and has nothing to recommend it over MDN or ECMA-262, in my opinion of course. ;-)

Comment: While this does convert to local time, it is not using angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

Add `UTC` at the end of the DateTime string before converting it to a date

example:

```
var date = new Date('2/16/2017 10:51:23 PM UTC');
console.debug(date.toLocaleTimeString()) // "5:51:23 PM"
```

Comment: That relies on implementation dependent parsing, which is never a good idea. "UTC" is not a time zone.

Comment: @RobG While UTC is not a time zone, it does convert a UTC time to browser local time. I agree it's not the best solution, but DateTime is hard, and this gets the job done.  How would you suggest converting between the 2 timezones?